# Wordpress.org or wordpress.com for developing a dynamic website

Tags: wordpress, web, wordpress.com

I have developed lot of websites in asp.net, but its the first time I am trying a wordpress site. My client want to develop a site for their shop so that they can update pictures and text themselves in the future. The site should be with good graphic and they want it in wordpress. But I confused that should I go for wordpress.org or wordpress.com for making this website. Do the wordpress.org work like a CMS, so anyone can update the site without the technical knowledge.

Comment: WordPress.com limited access. You can't upload your own theme, Plugins but only available on WP.com u can install. For Developing use WP.org.

Answer (score 3):

WordPress.org provides the open source code for WordPress that you can run on your own website, with whatever plugins you choose. WordPress.com provides (free) WordPress hosting, but you are limited as to what plugins and configurations you can make to your site.

There are a bunch of details on the WordPress site under the page "[WordPress.com and WordPress.org](http://en.support.wordpress.com/com-vs-org/)."

Answer (score 2):

go to wordpress.org

it provide you wordpress

http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page for documentation

Answer (score 0):

You should use wordpress.org. In wordpress.org you can download Wordpress and Install it in your server.

Wordpress.com is a hosting company that host Wordpress websites.

Take a look at this article:
http://diythemes.com/thesis/rtfm/differences-wordpress-com-org/

Answer (score 0):

wordpress.org use your own server. it is a cms/blog software and has many plugins to customize it. you can create static sites for as home and the main menu. everything else like blog pages are dynamically inserted but you dont have to use it. you can customize your page theme and change css and also add js. your customer could change textes add and remove pictures. there will be a plugin where you can define a set of images which can be modified by a service your customer can use so it would fit i would say